# Designing an interface for document slicing/splitting

Tags: interface, document

I am given a PDF that consists of a series of scans, all concatenated together in a single file. I'd now like to allow the user to split said document into multiple documents for easy retriveal. It can easily happen that a connected topic spans multiple pages in the scan, and these pages should be exported together into a single file. What could be a sensible interface to allow the user to choose which pages should stay together and be extracted/exported into a single document?

I have considered a list of checkboxes (one for every page), where you'd select page numbers that stay together and then click an "Export" button, which would remove these pages from the list view and export them into a single file, but I'm unsure if that's a sensible design decision (since I have next to no experience in UX).

Comment: Easy to follow question, especially the first sentence adds important context  Can you add a __rough sketch or annotated screenshot__ illustrating your "considered" vision: Can't bring together Checkbox with Numbers

Answer (score 1):

**1. Think about what users should be able to do**

- How many documents should they be able to export to? 1-5? Infinite?
- How many pages does a single file hold?
- Are the pages to be extracted all subsequent (e.g. pages 3-10)?
- Do the users trigger all exports with one click or is each extracted document a step-by-step process?

It will be harder to design an intuitive interface that is super flexible and can do everything (batch export, infinite pages).

**2. Sketch an interface out on paper**

**3. Test it with real people to see if they get it**

For inspiration, have a look at how acrobat pro is doing it. You select a couple of thumbnails of pages and open the context menu "Extract pages". This will create a new document which you can then save.
[image]

Comment: Basic steps forming a solid design-process! Can we link them to UCD terms like: (1) User's Tasks & Requirements Analysis, (2) Paper Prototype, (3) Usability Test ?